# Div slide from top not slide to reveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the contents of a div to slide down from the top. All of the methods I have tried seem to 'reveal' the contents which is almost static. I want to slide down from off the edge of the screen and push the content too. How would I do this? [Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/s86enu0q/3/)

html

```
<div id="dolphin">
<div id="lizard"><img src="http://www.beardeddragon.co/image/cache/data/blackhat-500x500.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

css

```
#lizard {
padding:50px;
display:none;
}

#dolphin {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dolphin").click(function(){
        $("#lizard").stop().slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Comment: "...but at the same time I need `#flip` to be `fixed`" ? Is that correct? Try also to use the right names... *Flip* for somethign that actually does not flips is funny :)

Comment: Hi yes I would like the div to remain fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move things with negative margins to create a slide effect instead of a reveal effect.

This is a very rough example but you can see how it's originally hidden with `margin-top: -100%;` and revealed by setting `margin-top` to `0`;

```js
$(".slide-button").click(function(){
  $(".lizard").toggleClass('slideit');
});
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div {
  text-align: center;
}
.slide-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.lizard {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.lizard img {
  margin-top: -100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.lizard.slideit img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-button">slide it</div>
<div class="lizard">
  <img src="http://www.beardeddragon.co/image/cache/data/blackhat-500x500.jpg">
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/qjfgsrL0/1/